# Bad image error on any exe files in Windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, operating-system, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04

I recently dual booted my Acer aspire E15 laptop with Ubuntu. The Ubuntu was working fine but when I opened the windows from grub menu, wireless networks like wifi wasn't detected and any exe files are not opening rather a bad image error is popping up which reads:

```
“Example.exe – Bad Image”
“C:\Windows\AppPatch\example.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0xc000012f”
```

It comes up when I open any kind of exe files including even task manager.
I even deleted Ubuntu and included the partition created by Ubuntu into C drive. I guess I have made a huge mess of the PC by changing the settings. I tried regedit method as well but the value in AppInit_DLLs was null by default. I even tried resetting the pc but after 11% it is saying can't proceed,undoing the changes. Somebody please help, I have watched plethora of YouTube videos on this topic but to no avail. I did these changes in my bios  https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire as well given by Umar having 5 upvotes during dual booting. How can I undo everything just like my new computer with windows 10 or fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try contacting Microsoft Remote Assistance Support, they will format your PC via remote assistance. It worked for me.